# How can I get the port number of a Matlab StateFlow input given it's handle programmatically?

Tags: matlab, stateflow

I have the handle of a StateFlow input from a previous find result.  I'm trying to get the port number for that StateFlow input.   I've been using the sf('get',[handle#],[field name]) command for other fields like 'data.name', 'data.scope', etc. For example, given the image below if I issue the command, sf('get',301,'data.name') the result 'ABS_Vehicle_Speed' is returned. However I can't seem to figure out the command to get the current port number, 4, in this example.  Can anyone help me with this?

[image]